# Are outlet covers needed with tamper resistant electrical receptacles?

Tags: safety

When baby-proofing an electrical receptacle (aka, "outlet"), is it necessary to use covers:
[image: Electrical outlet covers]

When the electrical receptacle is ["tamper resistant"](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibeCCtpSctDspRte.jsp?section=23899&minisite=10021)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. In fact the packaging on my tamper resistant outlets specifically say NOT to use them.

Comment: I agree. Choose one method that works, and use it as intended.

Answer (score 2):

One of the scariest moments we've had with our daughter came from the use of outlet covers. Our daughter managed to pry one of the covers off and proceeded to put them in her mouth. I caught her just as she was trying to jam the saliva coated outlet cover back into the socket.  If you ever go the outlet cover route, make sure they are nearly people-proof instead of just baby-proof!

Comment: We have a number of off-white receptacles with white face plates (and white trim in the whole house).  After this and the previous responses, I will likely be replacing these with white TR receptacles so they look better and are more "baby-resistant".